# Oracle connection : Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I am new to Oracle, I've installed Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio, and after that I've added a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model, and finally i've tried to use entity framework like i used to do with sql server :

```
using(DbEntities dbentity = new DbEntities())
{
    var test = dbentity.mytable.ToList()
}
```

I am getting this error :

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework
>   Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

I've read about DbProviderFactories, but i don't know which provider i should use and its right paramaters. Besides I don't have the Oracle.DataAccess.dll referenced on my project.

- this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865249/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-it-may-not-be-install) did not help me, it talks only about sql server

I am stack at this point for hours, please do not mark as duplicate if you are not sure about the solution

Comment: I dont know Oracle, but from what I understand is that this is the preferrd SqlClient library [Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess)

Comment: it workd like a charm, many thanks

Comment: I have converted to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching from one type of database server to another often requires changing the client package you use to connect with it.

Sql Server would generally reference `System.Data.SqlClient'

Net Framework does contain the `System.Data.OracleClient`, but it has been deprecated. From what I understand; you would want to use the ODP.Net package: [Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess).